# How to display default image in image tag before lazy load

Tags: mobile, lazy-loading

How to display default image in image tag before lazy load script runs.
I have a page, which is taking more time to load in device because of content and image.

Is there any way to applying an default image for all the  tag before lazy load script runs?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Lazy loading]
Hi,
Please find attached image, it will be useful for you to implement lazy loading.